# How to set the position of a p5js button object relative to the canvas (0.0)?

Tags: javascript

When i create a button object in the p5js webeditor with a position of (0.0), it will appear in the  top left corner of the website. But i want it to appear in the top left corner of my canvas. The (0.0) location of my canvas. Is it possible to set the position of the button object relative to the canvas' (0.0) location?

Comment: can you give some example code of what you are doing

Comment: Not a clue what p5js is, but sounds like the element needs position set to relative and not absolute.

Comment: This is p5js for anyone that does not know - https://editor.p5js.org/. It is a solely js-based drawing 'app' of sorts

Comment: Also, the canvas (0,0) *is* the center of the canvas. However, you can change it, as seen in the p5js documentation - https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/position.

Comment: Here is a code example of what i mean:

let button;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(100, 100);
  background(0);
  button = createButton('click me');
  button.position(19, 19);
}

If if run this code, the button appears on (19, 19) on the screen.
But i want it to appear on (19,19) on the canvas.
So if i were to move the canvas to a different location on my website, the button would still be in the right place on the canvas. While now, it stays on the same pixel location (19, 19) on the screen (website).

Answer (score 0):

```
function setup() {
    var canvas = createCanvas(100, 100);
    canvas.parent("your-div-id");

    button = createButton('click me!');
    button.parent("your-div-id");
    
    button.position(0, 0, 'relative');  // or any other position type   
};
```

You can parent the canvas and the button (Any p5.Element) to a div then you just set the [position](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/position) with the third parameter, positionType. It can be static, fixed, relative, sticky, initial or inherit (optional) (Optional)